matlab runs script but doesnt plot on ubuntu
I downloaded matlab 2024b on ubuntu 24.04.1 LTD and when i try to plot matlab calculates the values but just shows a empty figure. While opening matlab through the terminal I only get the error failed to load lincaberra-gtk-module

Please contact mathworks for support. It is a paid, proprietary software.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Running third-party applications on Ubuntu. is listed as topics you may ask about. I don't see any reason why this question isn't perfectly on topic here.

Please include exact error message you get. Is it libcanberra-gtk that is missing?

@vidarlo It is not off topic. But only mathworks knows how the software works and can provide the necessary support.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Unless someone knows a reason for the issue and can provide it here.  Just because Mathworks provides paid support for Matlab doesn't mean you have to be ultra persistent about it.  Nor is your second comment accurate.

It worked for me with the following command:
matlab -softwareopengl

It is possible that your  graphics card is not compatible with OpenGL or the driver is not installed
